# Can't check what kind of block was broken in Minecraft Forge

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am new to programming in Java, and I am trying to learn how to create Minecraft mods with Forge. I am following a book called [Minecraft Modding With Forge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491918896) written by Arun Gupta & Aditya Gupta and working with Minecraft 1.7.10. When I do this:

```
import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraftforge.event.world.BlockEvent.BreakEvent;

public class DiamondOreTrap {
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void explode(BreakEvent event){
        if(event.state.getBlock() != Blocks.diamond_ore){
            return;
        }
        event.world.createExplosion(null,event.pos.getX(),event.pos.getY(),event.pos.getZ(),10,true);
    }
}
```

Two errors pop up: "pos" cannot be resolved to a field, and "state" cannot be resolved to a field.

Comment: I see them [here](https://takahikokawasaki.github.io/minecraft-resources/javadoc/forge/1.8-11.14.1.1320/net/minecraftforge/event/world/BlockEvent.BreakEvent.html). Are you sure you have the right library?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: More accurately, what *version of Minecraft* are you modding for? This is the fundamentally most important question you need to answer when seeking help.

Comment: my forge version is 1.7.10

Comment: you should drop modding for 1.7.10...let the old version die already... players are missing so much features 'cause mod devs still stick to this ancient version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a field of the BlockEvent.BreakEvent that only exists in minecraft Forge v1.8+.

Here is [the documentation for the event in 1.7](https://takahikokawasaki.github.io/minecraft-resources/javadoc/forge/1.7.10-10.13.2.1291/net/minecraftforge/event/world/BlockEvent.BreakEvent.html). As you can see, `pos` is broken out into `x`, `y`, `z`, and you have `block` and `blockMetadata` instead of `state`  in this older version of Minecraft and Forge.

I agree with others that if you want to get into minecraft modding, it's probably better to use online tutorials and work on v1.12 mods as the number of people staying on 1.7 is falling precipitously.

Comment: but for some reason when I used 1.12 forge, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

## Ok then, the problem is that those fields are for MC 1.10+

`event.state.getBlock()` references the `IBlockState` added in 1.10 so that modders didn't have to remember magic metadata numbers and could instead work on values like `FACING:NORTH` or `LIT:true`.

For 1.7.10 and earlier, you have to use Block / Metadata combinations manually.  Likely the replacement here would be `event.block` or `event.getBlock()`, I don't have a 1.7.10 environment set up, so I can't go check. Use your IDE to examine the event object and see what properties are available and if they require a getter function.

Similarly `event.pos.getX()` references `BlockPos` objects, which are a non-modifiable wrapper around the X, Y, Z coordinates that something is occurring at. The replacement should be `event.getX()` or `event.posX` or similar.

(If anyone happens to be on 1.8 or 1.9, I have no idea what state the codebase is in for those versions, for a lot of things it's similar to 1.7, but in other ways its more like 1.10 and as I did not do any modding for 1.8 or 1.9 I'm just completely ignorant).

I do, however, recommend that you update to a newer version.